# How do I find out my VRAM?

Tags: technical-issues

I tried some Skyrim visual overhauls and some of them asked my vram. How do I find it and where?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Run `dxdiag.exe` from the start menu
2. Click on the "Display" tab (or one of the display tabs when you have multiple monitors)

You can see the type of video card you have and its total video memory.

Answer (score 5):

- Press the Windows key, type Control Panel, and then press Enter.
- Under the Appearance and Personalization, click Adjust screen
  resolution.
- On the middle of the right-hand side of the screen, click the
  Advanced settings.
- A new window should appear with your video adapter's properties;
  similar to the image shown below.
- Your video card's memory is under the Adapter tab in the Dedicated
  Video Memory: section (shown below).

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Type Windows Key + R or search "Run" on your windows search bar to open the Run function.
2. Type "dxdiag" into the Run search bar then click ok.
3. If you get a notification about connecting to the internet then click yes (don’t worry it will not harm your computer or security)
4. A "DirectX Diagnostic Tool" tab will open
5. After opening the DirectX Diagnostic Tool tab, click on "Display" Now you can see GPU and VRAM information here.

[image]